# How to use information from a file to calculate the spatial average for other several files?

Tags: r, binary

Assume that I have a file called river and there is a region of interest in this file has the value=1.
The file that i want as a mask can be read as:

```
sd <- file("C:\\lai_28_06.bin", "rb")
river<- readBin(sd, integer(), size=2,  n=360*720, signed=T)
```

The code given bellow will extract a region from several binary files(366) and then will calculate the mean. As you can see, I selected the region by using (X<-c(450:455) ; Y<-c(140:145) ). Now I want to do the same thing but with using information from the file"river". By saying ,for example, when "river"=1,take the corresponding value (from the files listed under a) into account and then divide the sum of those values by the number of values (simply the mean).

```
a<-list.files("C:\\New folder (13)", "*.bin", full.names = TRUE)
X<-c(450:455) ; Y<-c(140:145) 
extract<-vector()
# construct a vector of file names and loop through
for (i in 1:366) {
    conne <- file(k[i], "rb")
    file<- readBin(conne, integer(), size=2,  n=360*720, signed=T)
    file2<-t(t(matrix(data=file,ncol=360,nrow=720)))
    extract[i]<-mean(file2[X,Y])
    close(conne)
    }
write.table(extract,"C:\\yeinteg.txt")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the core of what you want (sloppy but effective):

```
rivermask<-matrix(NA,nc=360,nr=720)
rivermask[river==1]<-1
mean(file2*rivermask,na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: `lattice::wireframe` , or `graphics::rasterImage` may help.